# Cant send AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to update my table in the database using AJAX and PHP.
For this I make a gallery that shown from the database.
Foreach element I been saving the id as a rel attribute.

Once I click an image I want to send the id to PHP code and make the update.
But the id doesn't send (but it does save the variable) I check it using alert.

The only thing that doesn't work is the AJAX code:

```
<?php
$cat=categories_gallery::find_all();
if(isset($_POST['picker'])){
    echo $_POST['id_picker'];
}

?>

<link href="assets/css/image_picker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b99e675b6e.js"></script>
<p id="feedb"></p>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <?php foreach ($cat as $cat_gallery){ ?>
            <label class="option_item">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
                <div class="option_inner whatsapp fit_image" style="background-image: url('image/category/<?php echo $cat_gallery->image;?>');" rel="<?php echo $cat_gallery->id?>" >
                    <div >
                        <div class="tickmark" ></div>
                        <div class="name"  ><?php echo $cat_gallery->image_text;?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </label>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var update="update";
        /***Update Button Function  ***/
        $('.option_inner').on('click', function () {
            var id_picker=$(this).attr("rel");
            var picker='picker';
            $.post("image_picker.php", {
                    id_picker: id_picker,
                    picker:picker,
                },
                function(data){
                  $('#feedb').html(data);
                })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(data)` in the success handler? Have you tried checking the response in the Network tab of the Developer tools?

Comment: Try `$(this).prop('rel');`

Comment: Looks like a typo: the trailing comma after `picker:picker,`. Check the browser console before making the change, there is very likely an error message.